# Mirth Javascript IF coding issue

Tags: javascript, mirth

I am very new to Mirth and learning on the job.  I am basically needing to replace the wording in OBX3.1 based upon what is in OBX3.2  Here is the example:

Currently my OBX looks like this:

OBX|2|ST|EPSTEIN-BARR^EBV VIRAL CAPSID AG (VCA) AB (IGM)

What I need is to replace the wording OBX3.1 to EPSTEINBARRIGM any time EBV VIRAL CAPSID AG (VCA) AB (IGM) appears in OBX3.2  I will have several OBX segments throughout the record and this will not always appear in the same spot.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
var obxSegments = seg['OBX'];
var obxNum=obxSegments.length();

i = 0;
for each (var obx in obxSegments){
if (seg['OBX'][i]['OBX.3']['OBX.3.2']=='EBV VIRAL CAPSID AG (VGA) AB (IGM)')
 {
seg['OBX'][i]['OBX.3.1']=='EPSTEINBARRIGM'
}
i++;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please edit your question to include a code block, and add your current attempt (code) even if it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Added code to original post.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you're using `==` when you should be using a single `=` to assign the value of OBX.3.1. Here's an example:

```
for each (obx in msg.OBX) {
    if (obx['OBX.3']['OBX.3.2'].toString() == 'EBV VIRAL CAPSID AG (VGA) AB (IGM)') {
        obx['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'] = 'EPSTEINBARRIGM';
    }
}
```